# SublimeREPL Python - Run Current File not working due to Python system build

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed SublimeREPL to interact with my python code via Anaconda Package Control.

```
NameError: name 'tony' is not defined
```

I noticed that I am getting a NameError on a simple input function.

The error is caused by the python version difference between SublimeREPL(python v2) and my Sublime Python Built Systems version(v3).

I followed this [post](https://coderwall.com/p/nhq2gg/setting-up-sublimerepl-with-python3) to upgrade SublimeREPL to version 3, however, you can not edit Main.Sublime-Menu. Please advise on best steps to take in order to update SublimeREPL to Python v3.

```
def greetings():
       name_input = input('please enter your name:' )
       print('hello {}, please enter your age: '.format(name_input))
greetings()
```

[Sublime Text 3 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k19OI.png)

Comment: You don't need to edit any menus. You need to add a new Build System command... Tools > Build System. In VSCode, this would be "add new interpreter" option

Comment: @OneCricketeer actually, they *do* need to edit a menu to get this to work. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On macOS, the file you want to edit is located at `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu`. Open it up in Sublime as a JSON file. Go to [line 53](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL/blob/master/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu#L53) and change `python` to `python3`, optionally with a path preceding it if you know exactly where it's stored. For example, if you're using Homebrew, it might be in `/usr/local/bin/python3`. The line should now look something like this:

```json
                        "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
```

or this

```json
                        "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python3", "-u", "$file_basename"],
```

(this is the MacPorts location).

Save the file, and the menu option should now work.

Comment: Thanks Matt, it worked. I can not upvote your comment for my account is new on here. Note: in order to find the Application Support folder on MacOS, open Finder, click the "Go" menu, hold "Option", and click on "Library".

Answer (score 0):

great question and answer. note; you can use f-strings , improved string formatting syntax on your code, see below.

```
def get_user_input():
    name_input = input('please enter your name:' )
    print(f'hello {name_input}, please enter your age: ')
get_user_input()
```